# Redirect all HTTP requests to a website

Tags: windows, browser, localhost, hosts

How to configure windows to open the same static html page for all HTTP browser request.

For example if the user types http://www.google.com, my static Index.html will be shown.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you try and re-explain this question, it's hard to understand as it stands. Is your question asking that regardless of what URL they type, it always forwards to your own web page?

Comment: for example if user of that PC open any web site in his browser my static html file will be displayed

Comment: @TaronPro are you talking about blocking user access and displaying your page when they try ?

Comment: Yes that's right)), for all web sites

Comment: You have to install a transparent proxy on your network, and force all traffic through it. The installation depends on your network design, please add details in your questioni

Comment: Can you describe in more detail?

Comment: Please add details about your network infrastructure. (how does computers access the internet, do you have a hand on the router, what kind of router, etc.)

Comment: I have not access to router, I want to do it in machine

Answer (score 0):

You could update the hosts file on each PC (probably laborious).

You may be able to configure this in the router (depending on router).

You can install plug ins on the browser(s) which forward/redirect to a different URL (probably laborious).

Comment: I would like a do it without any third party application

Comment: How can I edit this file, what I should write there??

Comment: It seems you cannot use wildcards in hosts files, so that would be VERY laborious, and also it would not redirect ojly http, but all network traffic. that would probably break the computer's networking.

Comment: ok, can you say any plugin for google chrome??

Comment: No, you need to research it yourself